# Why does changing the order of conditionals break my code?

Tags: ruby

I have created a ping-pong test in Ruby. It monkey patches the `Fixnum` class with a new method, `ping_pong`, that loops over a range `(0..self)`, checks some conditions on each element, and constructs an array of the results.

The resulting array will have `Ping` for numbers in the range divisible by `3`, `Pong` for numbers divisible by `5`, and `Ping-Pong` for numbers divisible by both.

My question now is, why does the code only work if the part:

```
elsif (num.%(3) == 0) && (num.%(5) == 0) array.push("Ping-Pong")
```

is ahead of the other `elsif` statements? I tried putting it after the other `elsif`s but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:ping_pong) do
    array = [0]
    total = (0..self)
    total = total.to_a
    total.each() do |num|
      if (num == 0)
        array.push(num)
      elsif (num.%(3) == 0) && (num.%(5) == 0)
        array.push("Ping-Pong")
      elsif (num.%(3) == 0)
        array.push("Ping")
      elsif (num.%(5) == 0)
        array.push("Pong")
      else
        array.push(num)
      end
    end
    array
  end
end
```

Comment: When is it considered that it works?

Comment: how i posted the code, it works fine, but if i move first elsif statement to lets say second or third it wont work.....only works in that order of elsif

Comment: Voting to reopen. It's a beginner's question, but seems perfectly valid, and well enough written following Drenmi's edit.

Comment: In conditionals chained like this, always put more specific ones at the top. Otherwise, they'll never run, because more generic condition will match first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have multiple `if`/`elsif` blocks chained together, only one of them will run, and the first block to have a true condition will be the one to be run. So, the order of the blocks matters. For example:

```
if true
  puts 'this code will run'
elsif true
  puts 'this code will not run'
end
```

Even though the conditions for those blocks are both true, only the first one is run. If you want to have both run, use two separate `if` blocks, like this:

```
if true
  puts 'this code will run'
end

if true
  puts 'this code will also run'
end
```